# Codename One - UTF8 source non-ascii error

Tags: utf-8, codenameone

I have a problem with my Codename One Eclipse project. It was initially encoded in Cp1252, and after setting the encoding of the whole project to UTF-8 and replacing all non-ASCII char, the simulator is fine, but on devices, all non-ASCII char are messed up.

I'm currently not using the CN1 Localization API, but it's planned for future release, so all strings are hardcoded.

More, I retrieve some data from a webservice, and the non-ASCII char in the data are showing properly, so that's really a problem with the hardcoded strings.

Here are two screenshot, the first from the CN1 simulator, the second from my android phone (same problem on iOS device):

[Simulator ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFcDm.png)

[Android 6 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4YMa.png)

Any idea of what messed up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse javac is called in the `build.xml` and doesn't inherit the encoding of the project like the NetBeans version does. You will need to edit the build.xml and add the encoding attribute to these javac calls:

```
<javac encoding="UTF-8" ... >
```

Comment: Thank you Shai, it works like a charm :) But will my modification of the build.xml persist if the build.xml is updated after adding some librairies ?

Comment: Found it myself, the modification is needed after each update of the `build.xml`

Comment: When you add libraries build.xml isn't modified. It's only modified when it's out of date and we ask you whether you agree to the update so you should know that an update occured